# How to execute gcc with ignore certain syntax

Tags: c, gcc

I would like to run the following code 
`gcc -M [file]`

but, if i include _ FILE _ as shown below, you get an error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include __FILE__

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

so
Is there a way to run `gcc -M` over ignore certain syntax?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `#include __FILE__`?

Comment: Why do you use the c++ tag?

Comment: Do you even know what `__FILE__` is?

Comment: I'm making simple ide.
so I want to be prepared for what the user is typing.

Comment: Why do you want to handle this case for makefile generation if it won't compile anyway? Just tell the user that the makefile couldn't be generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question literally asked is: no. GCC provides no way to disable the error that is triggered by an unconditional `#include __FILE__`, nor several other related classes of errors, such as the one you get when a header file is missing or inaccessible.

An IDE does not need to do anything particularly graceful with these cases, because they will not occur in code that does anything useful.  Just expose the error message to the user.  (You might reasonably dispense with the 200 lines of "from test.c:2:" that precede the actual error.)

(In case anyone reading this is unclear on what `#include __FILE__` does, it causes the preprocessor to reread the file containing that statement from the beginning, as a nested include; in the absence of any other machinery, that will put it into an infinite recursion, which GCC cuts off at an "[arbitrary limit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/cpp/Implementation-limits.html#Implementation-limits)" of 200 includes deep.)